# Which Python exception should I throw?

Tags: python, windows, exception

I'm writing some code to manipulate the Windows clipboard. The first thing I do is to try and open the clipboard with `OpenClipboard()` function from the Windows API:

```
if OpenClipboard(None): 
    # Access the clipboard here     
else:
    # Handle failure
```

This function can fail. So if it does, I would like to raise an exception. My question is, which of the standard Python exceptions should I raise? I'm thinking `WindowsError` would be the right one, but not sure. Could someone please give me a suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Raise the windows error and give it some extra infomation, for example

```
raise WindowsError("Clipboard can't be opened")
```

Then when its being debugged they can tell what your windows error means rather than just a random windowserror over nothing.

Answer (score 3):

It is better to avoid raising standard exceptions directly. Create your own exception class, inherit it from the most appropriate one (`WindowsError` is ok) and raise it. This way you'll avoid confusion between your own errors and system errors.

Comment: I actually don't think you need to create a new exception from windows error when you can just call the original one with an argument.

Comment: @Jakob argument won't help you catch only your own exceptions.

Comment: But when you get the exception raised it contains additional infomation.

Answer (score 1):

WindowsError seems a reasonable choice, and it will record extra error information for you. From the docs:

> **exception WindowsError** 
>   Raised when a Windows-specific error occurs or when the error number does not correspond to an errno value. The winerror and strerror values are created from the return values of the GetLastError() and FormatMessage() functions from the Windows Platform API. The errno value maps the winerror value to corresponding errno.h values. ...